# Highlight list item in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the Bootstrap module for Drupal I've found the most recent version changes a style that was

```
.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:hover, .list-group-item.active:focus
```

to

```
a.list-group-item.active, a.list-group-item.active:hover, a.list-group-item.active:focus
```

Since my list items are not within `a` tags the `active` ones have lost their highlight. The style itself is very simple and I could reproduce it myself, but I'd much rather use the official Bootstrap way to highlight a li. What is it?

Comment: Use Chrome's dev tools and inspect the element.

Comment: I used Firebug to discover what I covered in the question. The style has changed to require an `a` tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no "official" bootstrap styling for an li element which is not within an anchor tag. You will have to add the styling externally.

Comment: That's a shame, it seems to me that highlighting an item is a common enough use case that it should be part of the framework. I'll just copy the link version's style.

Answer (score 17):

You must create your own class (e.g. `.list-group-hover`) and apply it to the `.list-group` element:

```
.list-group-hover .list-group-item:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the OP mentioned, the style for `<li>` elements worked in Bootstrap 3.0.0, but in the more recent 3.1.1 version, it was removed from the main bootstrap.css file. However, I did find it in the bootstrap-theme.css file, so maybe they decided it should be part of a theme and not part of the core of Bootstrap?

I also found that it is missing from a theme I downloaded from bootswatch.com, so they are probably following the bootstrap core's example and only allowing the **active** tag on `<a>` elements.